OOP Design: should I use generics or polymorphism in the base class?
I have a question regarding OOP design.
I have an abstract class Converter that takes a list of Documents as input, processes them in a specific way, and returns a new Document. The Converter class has several implementations.
The document that is input and generated as output can also vary —- it could be a PDF, plain text (string), or an image. Each implementation of the Converter class can only work with specific types of documents (e.g., only photos and PDFs, or only text and PDFs). The number of document types is expected to change constantly.
In the first version of the system, I made the document a generic type, but I realized that specific formatting is needed for each document type.
Now I'm considering a new design. Should I use generics in the base document class or use Object?
UML
abstract class Document<T>
=====================
content: T

class TextDocument implements Document<String>
class ImageDocument implements Document<Image>
...

abstract class Converter
====================
canWorkWith: List<Document<?>>
doWork(List<Document<?>>): Document

OR
abstract class Document
=====================
content: Object

class TextDocument implements Document
=====================
content: String

Which approach is better for this scenario and why?

There is no general best answer to this question, as it may depend on the domain but also the implementation language.
The general recommendation would be to use the order of preference:

Polymorphism via interface realization, especially if you use languages that have interfaces/protocols as core constructs, such as Java or Swift.  This approach leaves a huge liberty, as any class could be adapted to  implement Document interface.
Polymorphism via classes,  as this allows at the same time reuse of the common core of the different Document implementations and allow for maximum extensibility.
Generics (Templates in UML speak), if you need even more flexibility, and in particular if your type depends heavily on some type parameters used extensively in the implicit interface of the template type.

Generics implementation are very language specific and even in UML, there's a lot about template that remains purposely unspecified and which might create ambiguity (see also this UML answer about templates or this question about dependency management with templates) .  Some languages have serious constraints (in C++ for example it's compile time, and hence less flexible that changing a type at runtime as polymorphic design would allow) that reduces its suitability for some kind of problems.
Sometimes, the right design patterns allow to use polymorphism instead of generics:

You could for example inject some strategies at run time to process different parameter types.
You could use the prototype pattern with a clone operation when language semantics do not allow a polymorphic copy which would be obvious with enerics.
The GoF builder pattern also allows to keep a generic build process while generating different specializations.  By coincidence,  the GoF example of application of their builder is exactly a kind of converter between formats, like you have in your own example :-)


Thank you for your reply! You shared very good links and your words made me think.
My question was more focused on the Document class.
I want to make Converter work with an abstract Document class, but at the same time, I want to be sure that an implementation of Document class will return a certain content that is allowed for the specific Converter implementation -- I need it in the doWork method of Converter.

@MaYar I think I start to see but I am not sure to understand the problem. I am afraid your example is not comprehensive enough. I suggest the following: try to think of a solution using class polymorphism, and if you do not manage, share the example of converter design for converting a png document into a pdf document, but with the needed operations and parameters and return type, and show what is  blocking.

I would not recommend you use either approach. Both approaches are procedural in spirit. Now your Documents is data structures, not objects with a real behaviour (you might be interested in the following article: Anemic Domain Model by Martin Fowler).
This is what I would do:
I would define an interface Document.
interface Document {
    InputStream inputStream();
}

Next I would define implementations with constructors that receive what needs to be transformed.
TxtDocument:
class TxtDocument implements Document {

    private final Path pathToTxt;

    TxtDocument(Path pathToTxt) {
        this.pathToTxt = pathToTxt;
    }

    @Override
    InputStream inputStream() {
        // input stream with txt
    }
}

PdfDocument:
class PdfDocument implements Document {

    private final TxtDocument txtDocument;

    PdfDocument(TxtDocument txtDocument) {
        this.txtDocument = txtDocument;
    }

    @Override
    InputStream inputStream() {
        // input stream with pdf
    }
}

For example, now converting an TXT into PDF and then writing it to a file will look like this:
Files.copy(
       new PdfDocument
           (new TxtDocument(Paths.get("/path/to/some.txt")))
               .inputStream(),
       outputPath,
       StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
);

P.S.

I have provided fragments of Java code, but the main idea here is that it can be transferred to any object-oriented language.
By wrapping objects into each other you can build transformation chains.
You can create multiple constructors that accept objects of different types as input.
I assumed that the result will then be saved to disk or transmitted over the network, so I defined the Document interface this way. In essence, for code that will save the result to disk or transmit it over the network, no matter what implementation to work with, it will use the Document interface (polymorphism).

